# How to get width of device (not viewport)?

Tags: html, css, media-queries, viewport

I'm making my first website and my `meta` tag just defines a constant width instead of taking the device width, because I am having fun with CSS animations and wanted to avoid making it dynamic. Most of it looks fine on mobile except things that need to be centered. When I center it based on percentages, it centers based on the width I set (my viewport) as opposed to the width of the device. This is not a bug, of course, but I was wondering if there was a way for me to get the width of the device even if I don't set it as the viewport, so I can just calculate the `left` attribute to center it. Any ideas? Thanks!

I didn't put code because there really aren't any issues, it is more of a how-to question.

Comment: You can do this using a method in javascript `window.innerWidth;` I've added an answer for you regarding it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find the current width of your html body (device), you can try this javascript code `window.innerWidth;`

Try running this code and resize your windows to different widths:

```js
function myFunction() {
  var wid = window.innerWidth;
  document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = "Width: " + wid;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="myFunction()">Show</button>

<div id="display"></div>
```

ps: click on Run Code and then click on full page so you can resize your browser and test my snippet. It will show you the current width.

Comment: Yup, this is what I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes some users do not maximize their browsers when it comes to desktop devices. But you can try taking the "body" width of your application by creating a variable. Something more advanced is to check if there is any positive variation of that value during navigation. On mobile devices that value would be a bit more precise, unless the screen is rotated.

```js
your_var_name = document.body.clientWidth
```

Comment: Here are some guidelines for [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).  This provided answer may be correct, but it could benefit from an explanation.  Code only answers are not considered "good" answers.  From [review](https://stackoverflow.com/review).

Comment: Sorry, maybe I'm nervous because it was my firts answer. I will try to make ir better.

Comment: @WilliamEnriquePereiraCarras Thanks for the response! Unfortunately, `clientWidth` still returns only my set width rather than the device's width.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend **flex css** attribute.

https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

html

```
<div class="wrapper">
    wrapper
    <div class="inner"> inner </div>
</div >
```

css

```
.wrapper {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        width: 200px;
}
.wrapper .inner {
    width: 50px;
}
```

or

Using absolute and relative

```
wrapper {
    position: absolute;
    width: 200px;
}

wrapper  parent {
    position: relative;
    width: 50px;
    left: calc( 100% - 25px );
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately, neither of these changed the outcome.